# How to check type of generic object in a method?

Tags: .net, vb.net

For example say I want to accept the a generic list of elements as a method parameter and perform a different action based on the type of object that is making up the list. For example:

```
Private Sub DoStuff(Of T)(ByRef list As List(Of T) 
    If list.GetType() Is TypeOf(List(Of String) Then
        'Do some string stuff
    Else If list.GetType() Is TypeOf(List(Of Integer) Then  
        'Do some Integer stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

If there is a way to just see what the type of `T` is, that would also work.  I also attempted to set my argument as `List(Of ParentClass)` see if the `TypeOf` of it is `List(Of SubClass)`, but then it says that the `List(Of ParentClass)` can never be of type `List(Of SubClass)` which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Basically the context for this is I'm wanting to convert DataTable objects returned from DB calls in my data access layer to typed lists of objects that approximately model the tables.  I was thinking it might be nice to have one method that performs this function.  I was also thinking it would be best to avoid sending a DataTable object outside the data access layer.  What is the most elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9):

You can compare the generic type `T`, like this:

```
Private Sub DoStuff(Of T)(ByRef list As List(Of T))
    If GetType(T) = GetType(String) Then
        'Do some string stuff
    Else GetType(T) = GetType(Integer) Then  
        'Do some Integer stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Or, you could even do it as a `Select` block:

```
Private Sub DoStuff(Of T)(ByRef list As List(Of T))
    Select GetType(T) 
        Case GetType(String)
            'Do some string stuff
        Case GetType(Integer)
            'Do some Integer stuff
    End Select
End Sub
```

It goes without saying, but I suppose that I should add, that checking the type like that **should be discouraged and avoided if at all possible**.  Doing something like that will lead to messy spaghetti-code and it kind-of defeats the whole purpose of using a generic parameter.  Usually, when you start needing to do something like this, it's a good indication that you're doing something poorly and you need to rethink your design.

As far as the `List(Of ParentClass)` and `List(Of SubClass)` mismatch, that's a common confusion that people have with generics.  The way generics work is, each possible type that can be provided for the generic-type parameter will be treated as a completely separate data type, completely unrelated to any other data type.  So, `List(Of X)` and `List(Of Y)` are treated as completely different types, regardless of the relationship `X` and `Y` may share.  In other words, it's essentially short-hand for creating new types, like this:

```
Public Class ListOfSubClass
    Inherits List(Of SubClass)
End Class

Public Class ListOfParentClass
    Inherits List(Of ParentClass)
End Class
```

If you did that, you wouldn't expect `ListOfParentClass` to be compatible with `ListOfSubClass`, since they don't have any relationship to each other.  In the same way, you shouldn't expect generics to work that way either.

**Edit**

While what I had said about the casting incompatibility between different types of the same generic class is true, it's no longer the whole story. As of visual studio 2010 and the 4.0 version of the framework, .NET supports covariance and contravariance which helps to solve that problem. See the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to inspect the generic parameter to determine a code path, then your method is not truly generic and this case should be handled using overloaded methods:

```
Private Sub DoStuff(ByRef list as List(Of String))
Private Sub DoStuff(ByRef list as List(Of Integer))
```

This works equally well when using `ParentClass` and `SubClass` -- the most specific overload will be invoked.

If there are shared aspects of `DoStuff` that truly are generic, extract those into another helper method.

That said, you can check the type of `T` using `GetType(T)`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just create an extension method with the same name for each type of generic list?

in C# something like:

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>();
listOfStrings.DoStuff() //the extension method

var listOfInts = new List<int>();
listOfInts.DoStuff() //the extension method
```

The extension method would look something like:

```
public static class listExtensions
{
   public static void DoStuff(this IList<string> theList)
   {
       // Stuff with strings
   }
   public static void DoStuff(this IList<int> theList)
   {
       // Stuff with ints
   }
}
```